# Создание приложений под iOS

Tags: ios

Расскажите, пожалуйста, как создавать приложения под iOS? Насколько я почитал, нужно покупать средства разработчика за 99$, но а если не для распространения? Я просто пока что покупать не хочу, сначала хочу научиться их делать. Подскажите, пож-та, на чём их пишут?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону Objective C

Comment: "на чём их пишут". ИМХО, при наличии желания, самой большой проблемой будет не язык программирование, а, непосредственно, mac :DDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишут на Objective-C. У Apple имеется подробная документация с удобной навигацией и примерами кода.

Платить нужно только в том случае, если Вы хотите загружать приложение на своё физическое устройство (iPhone, etc..). Никто не мешает разрабатывать на симуляторе, которые поставляется вместе со средой разработки Xcode. Большой минус симулятора - это отсутствие работы с камерой и работа с максимум двумя тачами.

Comment: Xcode бесплатный, но нужна MacOS :-)

Comment: Ясно, но на симуляторе я не проверю акселерометр, верно?

Comment: Mac OS - не проблема, поставил виртуалку и всё)

Comment: Даже у виртуалки немало своих требований